# errors when i'm compiling my project

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, cpp-netlib

when i'm compiling my project i will get a lot of errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cpp-uri, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  uri_builder.cpp
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(45): error C2065: 'void_': undeclared identifier
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(46): error C2923: 'network_boost::mpl::is_void_': 'void_' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(51): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'network_boost::mpl::is_void_' is not a specialization of a class template
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(63): error C2065: 'void_': undeclared identifier
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(64): error C2923: 'network_boost::mpl::is_not_void_': 'void_' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(69): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'network_boost::mpl::is_not_void_' is not a specialization of a class template
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'network_boost::mpl::is_void_' is not a specialization of a class template
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): error C2059: syntax error: '<'
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): error C2447: '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(72): error C2913: explicit specialization; 'network_boost::mpl::is_not_void_' is not a specialization of a class template
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(72): error C2977: 'network_boost::mpl::lambda': too many template arguments
1>  c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(71): note: see declaration of 'network_boost::mpl::lambda'
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(72): error C3646: 'is_le': unknown override specifier
1>  c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(72): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'network_boost::mpl::lambda<Tag>' being compiled
1>c:\gta-five\multiplayer\vendor\cpp-uri\src\boost/mpl/void.hpp(72): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

i must get a cpp-uri.lib but i get a huge list of errors

vs2015 boost 1.58

Comment: Paste one of those messages into Google.  I'll bet you aren't the first person to encounter these.  Learning how to get yourself out of holes is a key skill.

Comment: Without any code samples, it becomes pretty difficult to help. From a quick glance, it seems like you have syntax errors. Did you write the program?

Comment: @duffymo sorry, but i didn't find that in google :(

Comment: I did: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0eya6e3a.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The below link could help you fix this, 
[Undeclared identifier (error C2065) in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539396/undeclared-identifier-error-c2065-in-c)

Basically, looks like you have not included the "using namespace" or missing out on adding few headers